# How to accept or deny a friend request with Parse?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, request

Right now the "Friend" component in my app lists every user that has signed up for the app. User A can then add as many friends as they want and interact with them.

What I want to do is allow User A to send a request to those users so that User B, User C, etc. can either accept or deny the request to interact with User A.

Here is what I have tried.

I have a new class called Friendship that contains:

toUser - points to the User class

fromUser - points to the User class

status - string

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friendship"];
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query whereKey@"status" equalTo:@"pending"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        //NSLog error
    }
    else {
         self.followingArray = objects;
         [self.myTableView reloadData];
    }
```

Objects is not returning anything.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest a `FriendRequest` class as follows:

```
Class: FriendRequest
fromUser (pointer:User)
toUser (pointer:User)
status (string)
```

Your operations are broken down into the following:

- Show pending requests sent by me
- Show requests awaiting my approve/deny
- Approve request
- Deny request
- Send a friend request
- Un-friend a user

Showing pending requests would be a matter of doing a query against the `FriendRequest` class where `fromUser` is the current user where `status` is "pending".

Showing requests awaiting action would be a query against the `FriendRequest` class where `toUser` is the current user where `status` is "pending".

Approving a request would mean updating the `FriendRequest` record to have a `status` of "approved" and adding each users to the others Friends list (probably a relation field on the User class).

Denying a request would mean updating the `FriendRequest` record to have a `status` of "denied".

Sending a friend request would check to see if there is any existing record where `fromUser` is the current User and `toUser` is the target, or `fromUser` is the target and `toUser` is the current User, regardless of `status`. If there is an existing record, don't allow another request (unless you want to set some rules about this, e.g. can send a new request after 30 days, which would require storing the last request date). If no record was found, create a new `FriendRequest` record with a `status` of "pending".

Un-friending would mean removing the users from each others friends relations, and updating the `FriendRequest.status` to "unfriended".

Bonus points if you add an ability to see rejections/unfriended records.

Comment: Couls you show some code on how to make a class? I'm a little confused. Would it add that to parse?

Comment: In the Data Browser on parse.com, an object is called a "Class", in your code it is just another Parse Object. Some (most) languages allow you to create a class to represent the object type, but that is optional.

Comment: @TimothyWalters thats a useful answer, just going a little further with it. How are the users actually connected once a friend request is accepted? is this in another object where the shared info is stored?

Comment: @Dano007 I guess you would just look up the Friendship Class and figure out if it contains both users with a status of "approved"

Comment: @TimothyWalters I have been looking at your code recently and using it to create a friend system in Parse. I have also seen many more recent posts that talk about adding and keeping track of friends in cloud code, and also setting up ACL's there. I'm just trying to process all of this and figure out the best way to proceed... any tips? Also, it would be amazing, since so many people need this feature, if there were some objective-C sample app set up. Especially with the cloud code/ACL stuff if that is now the way to go. I would even purchase it if given the opportunity!

Comment: Reference for above comment: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-v-how-to-make-friends/

Comment: @SAHM here's a couple of articles I wrote about it a while back, using JavaScript and Parse, but easy enough to convert JavaScript to anything: http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au I might do a version with Swift code, unlikely I would do Objective-C though, Swift is much more fun for iOS.