# Creating Relation one - to - one Parse User

Tags: relationship, parse-platform

I state that Parse.com use for my app

Does anyone know what 's the right way to create a list of friends? 
 The user must be able to create a relationship with another user.

I tried to take a look at AnyPic but I could not follow. seems very complicated for me ... I know there is the possibility of creating a relationship with PFRelation but did not find much nl web

Can you help?

Thank's Rory

Comment: This is pretty similar to the last question you asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872399/contact-user-one-to-one-using-parse). If you are just trying to learn how Parse works, and don't want to worry about using a many-to-many relationship yet, you could have a class "Friends", where each row is a tuple of friends. From there you can easily write queries to determine who is friends with who, how many friends someone has etc.

Comment: Hello Ahar, this question was directly about how to save a relationship between two users ... The other question was to understand if you could implement one to one on one chat ...

Anyway I really needed to understand the "Report" would be much easier for me! : D

Comment: Forgive me ... My translator is flakey: (
I meant that it would be easier for me to understand how to make a PFRelation between a user and the other so you can create a list of "friends" of the user and from these "Friends" to receive information about their post etc. ...

So as a first step I wanted to create this list of "Friends"

Comment: I think you should give a proper go at working through all the iOS examples in the [Parse.com iOS guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS) Each concept is presented with a really clear example. After this, work through the Anypic example, if it is too complex, break it down into chunks, and spend a day understanding each chunk. You will find things much easier in the long run if you have a proper understanding of things.

Comment: I know ... believe me, these days I'm trying and trying again: (

Comment: I think I managed to solve ...
In my detailview Controller (User profile) there is a button called "Follow Me"

That 'the code of the button

The object "Dettaglio" is that used for the prepareforsegue
Think will be good? button works perfectly, it creates the Relation but I wanted to have certainty about the code used .. If I have done well or done badly
`- (IBAction)seguilo:(id)sender {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationforKey:@"UtentiSeguiti"];
    [relation addObject: self.Dettaglio];
    [user saveInBackground];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have both sides be able to see the friendship you have two options:

- duplicate the relationship, i.e. a PFRelation on each PFUser
- us a many-to-many table, i.e. a new Class with two PFUser references, and possibly other information

Given that you might want more information about the relationship (e.g. status=requested/accepted/rejected, etc), I would suggest option two.

Here's a similar question on [managing friend requests and friend lists using Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167233/how-to-accept-or-deny-a-friend-request-with-parse).

Comment: Hello Timothy! This you suggested would be really nice but they are the first steps alone and do not know how to do, specifically ... Is there any tutorial on what you said or you have some practical example ... ? I do not know where to start ... Surely it is a good solution and I'd like to try, it is also very tidy.

Comment: If I had more free time I would gladly write up a tutorial on the topic, but alas as a single dad free time is in short supply. I don't know of any existing tutorial, though I would gladly contribute some time to help write one.

Comment: The children come first! : D you're right ...
Timothy there 'no way to accomplish what you said even if they are a beginner?

It 'really interesting your solution: (

Comment: I added a blog post explaining it, lets see if I get time to add some code samples. http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/a-parsecom-tutorial-implementing.html

Comment: Hi! timothy thanks for your blog .. I have not done tests, but I'll keep you informed. now I have a problem with ios7, as you implement a cell with variable height depending on the content of a label? I'm not Foumd tutorial on ios7 or xcode5

Comment: Hello Timothy, I am studying the way to create friendships and I have a little doubt ... How can I retrieve a pointer in a query? When I call, for example "RelationWith" (which contains the user pointer) does not show me his name and also the app crashes ...

Comment: You will want to read up on relational queries, specifically the `includeKey:` method. https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS

Comment: Hello Timothy'm trying to do what you suggested but my little experience I'm having some problem ... could you help me?

a greeting Rory

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469533/parse-com-retrieve-boolean-value-in-tableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

then, I had to make a query where I drew all the posts of my users (Timeline) and their names ... I had a problem (same as what I here to do this' you suggested) or call in a query of the Pointer ...

I solved so
This is the content of the cell

```
 NSString *user = [[object objectForKey:@"Utente"] valueForKey:@"Nome_Cognome"];
    cell.FFNomeLabel.frame=CGRectMake(15, -35, 270, 100);
    cell.FFNomeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.FFNomeLabel.text = user;
    [cell.BiancaView addSubview:cell.FFNomeLabel];

NSString *img = [[object objectForKey:@"Utente"] valueForKey:@"foto"];
    cell.FFImmagineUtente.file = (PFFile *)img;
    cell.FFImmagineUtente.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70);
    [cell.FFImmagineUtente.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.FFImmagineUtente.layer setCornerRadius:35.3f];
    cell.FFImmagineUtente.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.FFImmagineUtente loadInBackground];
```

What do you think?

Also how can I save a pointer that is not a Current User?

I saw the documentation parse, but having little experience I was not entirely clear :)